# Is there a way to set patch color for multiple patches with a single line of code in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

Right now i am using

```
ask patch 1 1 [set pcolor grey]
ask patch 1 -1 [set pcolor grey]
ask patch -1 1 [set pcolor grey]
ask patch -1 -1 [set pcolor grey]
```

Is there a way to set patch color for multiple patches with a single line of code in NetLogo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way:

```
ask (patch-set patch 1 1 patch 1 -1 patch -1 1 patch -1 -1) [ set pcolor grey ]
```

(The following has been updated in response to Seth's comment:)

If this is being run from the observer (that is, it's not being run by any agent) you can use [`at-points`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#at-points) like so:

```
ask patches at-points [[1 1] [1 -1] [-1 1] [-1 -1]] [ set pcolor grey ]
```

However, if this code is run by a turtle or a patch, the list of coordinates will be treated as relative to that agent. So `patches at-points [[1 0] [0 1]]` will give the patch to the right and the patch above the current agent. You can easily make a version that uses absolute coordinates:

```
to-report patches-at-coords [ coordinates ]
  report (patch-set map [patch first ? last ?] coordinates)
end
```

and then use it like so:

```
ask patches-at-coords [[1 1] [1 -1] [-1 1] [-1 -1]] [ set pcolor grey ]
```

Regardless, unless you're doing this a lot, I'd go with the first method.

Comment: The naming here seems a bit confusing to me since `patch-at` uses relative coordinates, but your procedure uses absolute coordinates. Note that the relative-coordinate version of your procedure already exists; it's called `at-points`.